# HTML image with "object-fit contain" not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I want to split the browser window in 4 areas of the same size and center images in it.
It works good in Chrome, but Firefox is using the full width, so a scrollbar appears and the areas do not fit on the screen.

What can I do to make it work in Firefox?

This is my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <style>
      body {
          display: grid;
          height: 100vh;   
          margin: 0; 
          grid-template-columns: auto auto;
          grid-template-rows: auto auto;          
      }
      div {
          display: grid; 
          margin: 10px; 
          border: 10px solid red;
      }
      img {  
          object-fit: contain; 
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
      }
   </style>
   <body>
      <div>        
         <img src="https://www.amaten.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/baum-amaten-herbst.jpg">
      </div>
      <div>        
         <img src="https://www.amaten.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/baum-amaten-herbst.jpg">
      </div>
      <div>        
         <img src="https://www.amaten.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/baum-amaten-herbst.jpg">
      </div>
      <div>        
         <img src="https://www.amaten.it/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/baum-amaten-herbst.jpg">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Firefox:

[image: Firefox]

Comment: use 1fr instead of auto and min-height:0 to the div

Comment: ^ min-height should be enough

Comment: `div{ min-height: 0}` should work, in Firefox there is a problem when you don't specify height to div.